# Not seeing error message with jqueryvalidation and msdropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

This may be a bit confusing but I'll try my best to explain it clearly.

I have a twitter bootstap form that is collecting information and its using jqueryvalidation to enforce specific rules on the form. So far everything is playing nice together. However, when using msdropdown [msdropdown](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) *at the client's request to format a select dropdown box* the error that should normally be seen on a required drop down is hidden. The form enforcement still occurs but you can't see the standard "This field is required" message. Using Chrome's web tools I can see the message and I see that it's behind the drop down.

Fiddle example: [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mwoods98/j0w0qbfv/5/)

I'm guessing there is probably a way to change the location of the error block in this case but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
    $(function() {

  $.validator.setDefaults({
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element)
        .closest('.form-group')
        .addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
      $(element)
        .closest('.form-group')
        .removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      if (element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
      } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    }
  });
```

Example of error block.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: So I started playing around with the error block I was able to get an error message to appear also sorry the fiddle was wrong :(:

```
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
  if (element.prop('type') === 'radio' || element.attr("name") == "newAssignment" ) {
    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
  } else {
    error.insertAfter(element);
  }
}
```

Now I do get the error message to appear above the select box but after I make a selection, the error message stays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have this where it will at least work.

adding:

```
|| element.attr("name") == "newAssignment"
```

as listed above helped me with the placement of the error message.

I also got rid of the error message by evaluating the element when a selection is made:

```
$("#addNewAssignment").validate().element("#newAssignment");
```